# how to let program run when click start in web app

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service

I want to create a simulation which is always sending messages.
The code is simple. But the problem is I don't know how to let it run when I click start. It only runs when I click URL. I'm using nodejs.

[image]

By the way, my code is as below

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information.

'use strict';

// Connection string for the IoT Hub service
//
// NOTE:
// For simplicity, this sample sets the connection string in code.
// In a production environment, the recommended approach is to use
// an environment variable to make it available to your application
// or use an x509 certificate.
// https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security
//
// Using the Azure CLI:
// az iot hub show-connection-string --hub-name {YourIoTHubName} --output table
var connectionString = 'xxxxxxx';

// Using the Node.js SDK for Azure Event hubs:
//   https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-node
// The sample connects to an IoT hub's Event Hubs-compatible endpoint
// to read messages sent from a device.
var { EventHubClient, EventPosition } = require('@azure/event-hubs');

var printError = function (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
};

// Display the message content - telemetry and properties.
// - Telemetry is sent in the message body
// - The device can add arbitrary application properties to the message
// - IoT Hub adds system properties, such as Device Id, to the message.
var printMessage = function (message) {
  console.log('Telemetry received: ');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(message.body));
  console.log('Application properties (set by device): ')
  console.log(JSON.stringify(message.applicationProperties));
  console.log('System properties (set by IoT Hub): ')
  console.log(JSON.stringify(message.annotations));
  console.log('');
};

// Connect to the partitions on the IoT Hub's Event Hubs-compatible endpoint.
// This example only reads messages sent after this application started.
var ehClient;
EventHubClient.createFromIotHubConnectionString(connectionString).then(function (client) {
  console.log("Successully created the EventHub Client from iothub connection string.");
  ehClient = client;
  return ehClient.getPartitionIds();
}).then(function (ids) {
  console.log("The partition ids are: ", ids);
  return ids.map(function (id) {
    return ehClient.receive(id, printMessage, printError, { eventPosition: EventPosition.fromEnqueuedTime(Date.now()) });
  });
}).catch(printError);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want your application running background continuously. So you could deploy your nodejs file as a webjob. Full documention about Azure Webjobs here:[Run Background tasks with WebJobs in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create).

This is a [blog](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/07/azure-webjobs-with-node-js.aspx) about Webjobs with Node.js. You need create a run.js file, then zip run.js with all dependencies(including the node_modules directory). Then upload the zip as a webjob. And in your requirement, the webjob should be continuous.